# Trouble with a loop

Tags: c++

I want my char run, to determine wether my switch will run or not. I am having trouble placing the start for the loop. 
I am creating a pattern using integers option and size. The option chooses the pattern type 1-4 and the size determines the number of columns and rows that the pattern will have.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int option, size;
char run;
cout << "This program is writen by Alex Walter. "
     << "The purpose of this program is to create four different patterns of different sizes. "
     << "The size of each pattern is determined by the number of columns or rows. "
     << "For example, a pattern of size 5 has 5 columns and 5 rows. "
     << "Each pattern is made up of character P and a digit, which shows the size. "
     << "The size must be between 2 and 9. ";

cout << "Menu" << endl
     << "1. Pattern One " << endl
     << "2. Pattern Two " << endl
     << "3. Pattern Three " << endl
     << "4. Pattern Four " << endl
     << "0. Quit " << endl;

cout << "Choose an option (between 1 and 4 or 0 to end the program): ";
cin >> option;
cout << "Choose a pattern size (between 2 and 9): ";
cin >> size;

do{
switch(run)
{

case 1:
            cout << "Pattern 1: " << endl << endl
             << size << "PPPP" << endl
             << "P" << size << "PPP" << endl
             << "PP" << size << "PP" << endl
             << "PPP" << size << "P" << endl
             << "PPPP" << size << endl;
break;

case 2:
            cout << "Pattern 2: " << endl << endl
            << "PPPP" << size << endl
            << "PPP" << size << "P" << endl
            << "PP" << size << "PP" << endl
            << "P" << size << "PPP" << endl
            << size << "PPPP" << endl;
            break;

case 3:
            cout << "Pattern 3: " << endl << endl
            << "PPPPP" << endl
            << "PPPP" << size << endl
            << "PPP" << size << size << endl
            << "PP" << size << size << size << endl
            << "P" << size << size << size << size << endl;
                break;
case 4:
            cout << "Pattern 4: " << endl << endl
            << "PPPPP" << endl
            << size << "PPPP" << endl
            << size << size << "PPP" << endl
            << size << size << size << "PP" << endl
            << size << size << size << size << "P" << endl;
                break;
}
cout << "Run again?" << endl;
cin >> run;
}while(run == 'y' || run == 'Y' );


}
```

I have only written enough code to create a pattern for the example. 
But I am also looking for a way to loop the creation of the pattern. Please don't just give me an answer I really am trying to figure this out I am just stuck and have no contact with any of the students in my class.

Comment: Where do you initialize `run` to anything?  You're getting undefined behavior because `run` is never initialized.  I think you want to your `switch` statement to use `option`

Comment: Those `cout`s are lovely

Comment: @Kunal are you joking?

Comment: @CharlesSalvia if my switch statement uses option to determine the pattern then how do i loop run again?

Comment: Agree with @CharlesSalvia. Adding to it, because run is a char, you should have cases like case '1' or 'a' and so on. Another polite suggestion - instead of copying and pasting your entire code which might have a bunch of irrelevant stuff, try to post just the part of the code that you have trouble with. Makes life easier for others who are looking into it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `run` for two separate purposes:

1. Input 'y' or 'Y' to continue running, or 'n' or 'N' to stop running.
2. Count the number of loops and use in the switch statement to determine which run you're on.

The solution is to have two separate variables instead.  Use `run` for #2 above, but then you need to initialize it, meaning give it an initial value at the very top of the program.  To initialize, provide the value where you declared it, like this:

```
int run = 1;
```

Notice I changed the type from `char` to `int` -- because you're comparing it to integers, not characters, in the cases of your switch statement.

Now make sure `run` is incremented (add 1 to it) every loop.  (You should also consider what happens if/when `run` reaches 5, which is not in your switch statement!)

```
++run;
```

Do this somewhere like after the switch statement.

Now add an additional variable, such as `input`, and use it instead of `run` at the bottom where you are getting input with `cin` and comparing it with 'y' or 'Y' in the `while` statement.  You can declare the variable at the top as well, and don't need to initialize it, although it's a good habit to get into to initialize it anyway:

```
char input = 'Y';
```